# banner badges iPhone

Tags: iphone, xcode4

Is there a way to have the banners/badges for my app only update to 1?  For example, if I have three notifications/updates for my app, instead of showing the launch icon on the homepage with the number 3, could I just show the number 1?

I guess in essence, I'm asking can I set the max of a badge for the app I am developing for the iPhone?

Comment: `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setApplicationIconBadgeNumber:1];`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You set the application badge yourself, so you can determine the algorithm for the number you display. So if you want to just set the badge to 1 if there are any messages, but no badge otherwise, just use something like this:

```
- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setApplicationIconBadgeNumber:(numberOfMessages > 0) ? 1 : 0];
}
```